# How to write a function that takes a list of strings as parameter and returns a result

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that accepts strings, joins them together into a single string separated by comma. The only thing I am having problem is creating a function out of it that has a return value. Below is my code snippet.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] answer = new string[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
    {
        answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    string line = string.Join(", ", answer);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: You mean something like `private static string Join(string[] answers)`?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a function taking an `string[]` array and returns a string which can either be done as:

```
Func<string[], string> func = answers => string.Join(", ", answers);
Console.WriteLine(func(answer));
```

or

```
public static string Join(string[] answers){
     return string.Join(", ", answers);
}
```

depending on what you mean by "function".

Comment: how will you call that in main method?

Comment: @AristotleDoria `Console.WriteLine(Join(answer));`. while you're at it. have a read at [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)  in C#.

Comment: i got an error when it comes to your code. ` static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Join(answers));
        }
        public static string Join(string[] answers)
        {
            answers = new string[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++)
            {
                answers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            string line = string.Join(", ", answers);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            return string.Join(",", answers);
        }`

Comment: @AristotleDoria do you have `answers` declared in your `Main()` method ? cause i don't think you have!

Comment: @Amit trying to avoid doing that and have the OP read the link about methods that I've just mentioned to him. ;-)

Comment: @AristotleDoria I am no one to lecture/advise you but I'll try to shed some light. the question you've asked is already at the most basic level possible and if you plan to succeed in programming you need to master the basics and research when you struggle and when you fall pick yourself back up and keep trying. I've just referred you to the C# Programming Guide and it seems you've just ignored it and expect me to do all the work for you... which is not fair on both me and you.

Comment: thanks for the concern. i'm new to c# programming and your advice is very helpful for me to succeed as a programmer. it's just i need to help myself if i want to be successful in this and sharp this skills as well..